# How to set a time limit for model object delete in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to set a time limit for object deletion in Django.

For example, the user can delete the object they submitted within 3 days; once the 3-days window is past, they can no longer delete the object. After that, only the superuser can delete it.

How can I achieve that? I tried lots of methods but none can do this...could someone help with the solutions?

Comment: users would be using only the django admin site?

Comment: What exactly have you tried (you say you tried lots of methods)?

Comment: Are you using your own views or the admin site? Are you using your own models or imported models from other packages?

Comment: I tried override the delete_model method in admin.py and redirect the delete process to the admin site for the user. problem is i can prevent the deletion process but the admin site will always give the success response(although the object is not deleted)

Comment: and i override the delete() method in model.py, but it kind of got me worried some bugs may happen because the document says when you override the delete method the object should be deleted. on top of that, the delete method from model.py cannot detect the user identity for the superuser to bypass it

Comment: I tried use the deleteview, and override the form_valid method but somehow the form_valid method never been executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. store the "object creation" date in the instance to be processed. use `DateTimeField` with [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to set the field to now when the object is first created..
2. before deleting compare how many days have passed since the creation, use [django signals pre-delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete) to trigger a check before executing the `delete()` and [timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965201/calculate-time-between-time-1-to-time-2) to calculate the age of the instance.
3. `raise` the correspondent error & `catch` when necessary

*pro-tip: if you write a Model method `obj.can_delete(self, user)` you can write logic for 2 and 3 here instead having it across different parts of the app, then you can ask `can_delete(user)` first in order to present warnings or deactivate buttons, the `user` instance works for the conditional statement to allow only superusers to delete ignoring the age contitioning.*

Comment: thanks seems the pro-tip is what i wanted. but one more question, in obj.can_delete(self, user), how to pass the current user to the parameter?

Comment: in an authenticated context, use `request.user`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to override the `delete()` method of the models and add a check there, maybe something like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone as tz

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']     # this may raise KeyError
    start_date = ...          # this probably would be a model field

    if user.is_superuser or (tz.now() < start_date + timedelta(days=3)):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise some error
```